# Expected random generation

Tags: probability

*Background:* I've been reading about how [Dota](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Pseudo-random_distribution) deals with its random generation.  There's another question on [Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161430/calculating-the-constant-c-in-dota-2-pseudo-random-distribution) about this, but it doesn't give a formula, which is what I'm looking for.

Therefore,

Let the probability of $E$ succeeding be $\min(A(N+1), 1)$ where $N$ is the number of previous successive failed attempts, and $0 \le A \le 1$.

For example, if $A$ is $25\%$, then on the first attempt, the chance of success is $25\%$, then $50\%$ on the next try, then $75\%$, and then finally $100\%$.  Once any attempt has succeeded, the success chance goes back down to $25\%$.

What is the average success rate (across an infinite number of trials)?  Is it possible to get this into a single formula?

Comment: The way you have it, the event always fails on the first try. Is that correct?

Comment: @CommonerG fixed, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by number of previous failed attempts? Is it total number in the past history or number of failed attempts in a row before right now?

Comment: Failed attempts in a row, updated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it might be easier just to work out the probabilities and expected number of attempts until a success directly from the probabilities and then take the reciprocal of this for the average success rate.  This is in effect what the `PfromC` function does in [one of the answers you link to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/178681). In effect the direct formula is $$\dfrac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\Big\lceil\tfrac1A\Big\rceil} n \min(nA,1) \prod_{m=0}^{n-1}(1-mA)}   $$

There may be a single-pass formula involving a sum, the ceiling function, and the Gamma function (which becomes a factorial when A is the reciprocal of an integer), perhaps

$$\dfrac{1}{\displaystyle \Bigg\lceil\frac1A\Bigg\rceil - \Gamma\left(\frac1A\right) \sum_{n=1}^{\Big\lceil\tfrac1A\Big\rceil -1} \dfrac{\left(\Big\lceil\tfrac1A\Big\rceil -n \right)n A^{n}}{\Gamma\left(\frac1A-n+1\right)} }  $$ though whether this is an improvement is open to question. I doubt you can simplify this much.

Here are some values:

```
A    average success rate
1    1
0.9  0.9090909
0.8  0.8333333
0.7  0.7692308
0.6  0.7142857
0.5  0.6666667
0.4  0.5813953
0.3  0.4980080
0.2  0.3983429
0.1  0.2732079
0.05 0.1889079
0.02 0.1170532
0.01 0.0819003
```

This is in effect the inverse of the table at the end of that linked answer.